# how to use if-else statement in accessor?

Tags: java

this is part of my program. I have to be sure that the amount of gas does not exceed the top gas capacity. I do not know how to write the else part? I ask the user to enter the current gas and it should be less or equal 30.

```
    private final int GAS_CAP = 30 

    public int getGasCapacity(int gasCapacity)
    {
       if(currentGas <= GAS_CAP)
       {
         gasCapacity = GAS_CAP - currentGas;
       }
       else gasCapacity = currentGas;
       return gasCapacity;
   }
```

Comment: You do not know that the else **what**?

Comment: So what exactly is the question, @JayLo?

Comment: What is `currentGas`? Why are you modifying the method parameter?

Comment: number one rule of programming, **it helps if you know what you are doing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final int GAS_CAP = 30 

public int getGasCapacity()
{
   int gasCapacity;
   if(currentGas <= GAS_CAP)
   {
     gasCapacity = GAS_CAP - currentGas;
   } else {
     gasCapacity = 0;
   }
   return gasCapacity;
}
```

Your else statement was wrong, and there shouldn't be a parameter. 
You could also easily accomplish this with one line, but I'm not sure if you know how to use ternary syntax.

Comment: you need to close the else block

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that's what I get for trying to add code in the text box itself! haha @PrasadKhode

Comment: Why would you initialize `gasCapacity` to `GAS_CAP`? If you leave off the initialization, the compiler will make sure you set `gasCapacity` in every code path. (And you can also declare it `final`, so that the compiler will make sure you set it only once in each code path.)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should make your question a little more clear because I don't really understand what you're trying to do. I'm going to write you what I think you're trying to achieve and you tell me if it's okay or comment what was wrong in the answer.

```
private final GAZ_LIMIT = 30;


public int ObserveGazCapacity(int gazCapacity)
{

 if(gazCapacity<=GAZ_LIMIT)
 {
   gazCapacity-=GAZ_LIMIT;
 }else{
    gazCapacity=0; //in case higher than limit, capacity will be at the maximum value permitted 
}
 return gazCapacity;
```

}

Hopes that what you're looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Can made in one line as,

```
public int getGasCapacity(){
   return (currentGas <= GAS_CAP ? (GAS_CAP - currentGas) : 0 );
}
```